# Can anyone help me make this code more simple and not so lengthy?

Tags: python, tkinter

**I am trying to make a hangman game but i feel like this could be simpler to code any suggestions?

```
buttonb = tkinter.Button(bg="blue", text = "B", width=2,command=ex)
buttonb.pack(side="left")
buttonc = tkinter.Button(bg="blue", text = "C",width=2, command=ex)
buttonc.pack(side="left")
buttond = tkinter.Button(bg="blue", text = "D", width=2,command=ex)
buttond.pack(side="left")
```

Comment: Loop over a list of letters and store the buttons in a list / dictionary. If necessary, use `ord` and `chr` to create the alphabet list.

Answer (score 0):

As [@meowgoesthedog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8204776/meowgoesthedog) suggested a simple loop is your answer.

```
import string
buttons = {}

for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
    buttonb = tkinter.Button(bg = "blue", text = letter, width = 2,command = ex)
    buttonb.pack(side = "left")
    buttons[letter] = buttonb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to iterate over the letters and since the buttons belong together they can be stored in a data structure like a list.

```
buttons = []
for letter in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ':
    button = tkinter.Button(bg="blue", text = letter, width=2,command=ex)
    button.pack(side="left")
    buttons.append(button)
```

Feel free to use a list comprehension if you like.